# SEO technique for website

Tags: seo

Could anyone help me to optimize my website in search engines if someone search it with key words "sherwood park taxi". My website URL is http://sherwoodparkonlinetaxi.com/.

Right now its coming at page 2 on Google search engine. So how  can I improve this so that my link appears on page one.

Also, If I search it with "sherwood park cabs" then my sites comes at place 2 in google thats very good but if I search with the same keywords on mobile device then it shows my website on page 2 which is very bad. So is there any difference in search the website on mobile device and searching it on normal browser. How can I improve my search on mobile device.

I am searching it on www.google.ca

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not send this to Pro Webmasters. Website reviews are not acceptable there and will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 h1 tags, reduce it to 1 and include "sherwood park taxi" in it.
So turn:

```
<div align="center"><h1>ARISTOCRAT CABS</h1></div>
<div align="center"><h1>SHERWOOD PARK TAXI SERVICE</h1></div>
```

into

```
<div align="center"><h1>ARISTOCRAT CABS<br>
SHERWOOD PARK TAXI SERVICE</h1></div>
```

Also, you should make a site map that includes all your pages and submit it to Google. Go to http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to create it if you do not already have a site map.  You can also manage other Google related SEO type things at [www.google.com/webmasters/tools/](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

Comment: Actually, there are 3 h1 tags on the front page... There should only be 1.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the robots.txt, and using gzip

and this may help you:
http://www.woorank.com/en/www/sherwoodparkonlinetaxi.com

if you have Chrome or FF you have many add ons that will help you with seo